# What is the difference between polyfill.io and core-js?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 2 docs tells us to use core-js to support some older browsers and Intl polyfill if this api is needed. But intl.js explain that it is now included in polyfill.io which serve (or not) the same purpose as core-js.

Thank you to tell me what are the differences between polyfill.io and core-js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've read, it seems that polyfill.io detects which browser you are using, and serves accordingly the requirements for that browser only, while core-js just contains all of it for all browsers.

If you are in an environment that is really dependent on file size, I guess polyfill.io would be a good choice.

But nowadays, are a few kBs really an issue (especially for SPAs) ?

Might be wrong, but that's how I understood it reading the official docs.

Comment: In my opinion both can be used. Core-js includes polyfills for ECMAScripts* that are not included in Polyfill.io and Polyfill.io includes polyfills for DOM APIs (as WebAnimations, etc).